# Capture Key Sequence via ProcessCmdKey

Tags: c#, keyboard

I override ProcessCmdKey in my application and can get any single keypress with modifiers (eg. Alt+Ctrl+X).  What I want to do is mimic the short cut handling of say ReSharper where the user holds down the control key and then R, M to open the refactor dialog

I have found plenty of references to capture key plus modifier combinations but not much for the sequence.  There is this [Capture multiple key downs in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/709540/capture-multiple-key-downs-in-c-sharp)  but it uses the KeyDown Event.

There are also key mining examples such as this http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/simple_key_log.aspx that capture everything and use native calls.

Am I able to extend my ProcessCmdKey to handle the key sequences or do I need to look elsewhere?  Since I have a large number of shortcuts captured in ProcessCmdKey I would rather not have to start again if possible

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to achieve the functionality you want you simply need to keep track of the sequence of `KeyPress` events.

You can create a class to keep track of the last key combination that was pressed in `ProcessCmdKey`.  If that particular combination does not match a mapped command but it is the first element of a sequence you can store it in your class. Then the next time `ProcessCmdKey` is activated check your new `KeyPressTracker` class to determine if a sequence has been started. If it has then check if the newly pressed key combination is the second element of one you specify.  Please see the pseudocode example below:

**Step 1:**  `ProcessCmdKey` is activated.  The key combination is <kbd>Ctrl+R</kbd>, this does not match a command that you want to process but it is the first element of a sequence that you want to use (<kbd>Ctrl+R+M</kbd>).

**Step 2:**  Store this key-press in a new class you created to keep track of the last key-press.

```
KeyPressTracker.Store(KeyCode, Modifiers);
```

**Step 3:**  `ProcessCmdKey` is activated a second time.  This time, the key combination is <kbd>Ctrl+M</kbd> which is not a key-press we're looking for but is the second element of a sequence.  We check the last stored keypress using the new `KeyPressTracker` class.  This will allow you to match a "sequence" such as <kbd>Ctrl+R</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl+M</kbd>.

```
var lastKeyPress = KeyPressTracker.GetLastKeyPress();

if (lastKeyPress == "Ctrl+R" && currentKeyPress == "Ctrl+M")
{   
    // Show Refactor dialog
}
```

Comment: Thanks I will certainly try this out