# How to write a function that determines if a key is down and a delay passed?

Tags: c#, refactoring, key, stopwatch

I have a function that looks like this right now:

```
public static bool IsKeyDownWithDelayPassed(Keys key, int delay)
{
    bool timeElapsed = stopWatch.ElapsedMilliseconds > delay;

    bool isKeyDown = currentKeyboardState.IsKeyDown(key);

    if (timeElapsed && isKeyDown)
    {
        stopWatch.Restart();
    }

    return timeElapsed && isKeyDown;
}
```

This works perfectly but it only works with one key at a time. For example, if I want to use the arrow keys and do diagonal movement (right and down arrow keys held down at same time), it doesn't work.

I thought of a solution that involved a `Dictionary` that mapped `Keys` to `Stopwatch`es but that seemed a bit overly complex. Am I missing something that could simplify this task?

Thanks.

Comment: Could you give a bit more info about what you are trying to do? Can't you use the keydown events?

Comment: @OskarKjellin: Yeah but I want to make a custom function that behaves identically to `KeyDown` except with the additional condition that an arbitrary delay has passed since it last returned true for that key.

Comment: What I meant is, can't you just subscribe to those events and then perform your logic on up / down

Comment: check this so post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/709540/capture-multiple-key-downs-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this:

```
Dictionary<Keys, DateTime> keytimes = new Dictionary<Keys, DateTime>();

public bool IsKeyDownWithDelayPassed(Keys key, long delay)
{
    if(!keytimes.Keys.Contains(key) || keytimes[key] == DateTime.MinValue)
        return false;
    long elapsed = DateTime.Now.Ticks - keytimes[key].Ticks;    
    return delay < elapsed;
}

private void KeyDownEvent(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    keytimes[e.KeyData] = DateTime.Now;
}

private void KeyUpEvent(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    keytimes[e.KeyData] = DateTime.MinValue;
}
```

Comment: Nice answer, how about returning `return delay < elapsed;` instead?  That will save you four lines of code.

Comment: @ChuckSavage thanks, the code was definitely needing some optimizations.