# keydown event does not stroke for some combination

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, keydown

I need to make a shortcut key combination of three letters (Ctrl+L+I)
I tried a lot to do so but no luck .
I tried it in this way

```
private void MDIParent2HOME_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Control && e.Keycode==Keys.L && e.KeyCode == Keys.I)
            {//login
                    Form1 chilform = new Form1();
                    chilform.MdiParent = this;
                    chilform.Show();
            }
       }
```

but this didn't work.

then I changed my key combination (ctrl+ALt+L) and tried it in same way

```
private void MDIParent2HOME_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Control && e.Alt && e.KeyCode == Keys.L)
            {//login
                {
                    Form1 chilform = new Form1();
                    chilform.MdiParent = this;
                    chilform.Show();
                }
            }
        }
```

and  I am wondering that worked perfect .I couldn't get the reason do anyone know about this behaviour of KeyDown event.Also help me if I can do the same with (ctrl+L+I) . Thanks

Comment: Aren't some key combinations peculiar to Windows System only?

Comment: I've marked the question as duplicate. Follow the link just above your post. It will help.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel the duplicate doesn't show how to capture two characters simultanously but rather after each other. So OP here seems to want `Ctrl + L + I` and not `Ctrl + L` + `Ctrl + I`.

Comment: @Default How about [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/709540/capture-multiple-key-downs-in-c-sharp)

Comment: @Default Take a look at my solution and try it

Comment: @SriramSakthivel yes, that's the one :) is it possible to "remap" it to that one instead?

Comment: @kyle I'm not the one asking the question. address the original poster instead.

Comment: @Default I can't do that, I can reopen, but I can't close it again. Someone has to do it :(

Comment: @SriramSakthivel well, I can cast a vote for it but I won't be single handedly able to close it. I guess leave it - it's among the comments anyway. Nice find!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmmm...I think my solution works

```
private bool IfSeen;

    protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
    {
        if (IfSeen)
        {
            if (keyData == (Keys.Control | Keys.I))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("You pressed Ctrl+L+I");
            }
            IfSeen= false;
            return true;
        }
        if (keyData == (Keys.Control | Keys.L))
        {
            IfSeen= true;
            return true;
        }
        return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure ?? have you tried ?? because it does not work that way at my end

Comment: My bad. Deleted original comment.

Comment: This is basically what the linked duplicate suggests. But [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29009120/keydown-event-does-not-stroke-for-some-combination#comment46264269_29009120) by @Default suggests that it is not what OP wants. I'm quite confused.

Comment: @thaoden no it is returning true only on ctrl+L+I

Answer (score 1):

You are checking for `e.Keycode==Keys.L && e.KeyCode == Keys.I`. I think e.Keycode contains only the value of a single key, `L` or `I`, but not both at the same time, so your check will always fail.

Note that `Alt`, `Shift` and `Ctrl` are modifiers and are handled a bit differently than other keys.

Comment: okay,thank you for fast response, is there any way if i need to  use L and I both?

Comment: None that I am aware of. I think (but am not sure), that only a single KeyDown event is registered when multiple non-modifiers are pressed. After all, you cannot type `LILILILI` in your text editor by pressing `L` + `I`.