# How to detect if multiple keys are pressed in C# forms

Tags: c#, forms, winforms, keyboard, key

I have looked for a solution to detect if multiple keys are pressed in **C#** (I couldn't find a solution!). 
I have this game with two players and I need to detect if a key is pressed to move them around.
(I'm Using C# Forms)
I've only found answers to detect if two keys are held down at the same time and they didn't help.

--EDIT--

How to detect if a key is pressed using KeyPressed (C#)

Comment: Probably this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/a/709641/3195195

Comment: @jeffrycopps Sorry but that didn't help, the answers only tell you how to detect if all the selected keys are pressed, not if any key is pressed.

Comment: I didn't get your question well. Keys pressed and held down are same I guess.

Comment: Crystal ball says that the real problem is that key repeat no longer works.  Something you should *never* rely on in a game since the repeat rate and cadence is a user preference.  Nothing that two *bool* variables cannot do.  Set them to *true* with the KeyDown event and back to false with the KeyUp event.  Use those bools in your game loop to determine where the game objects should move.  It completely does not matter that more than one player presses keys at the same time, you get the events one after another.

Comment: @jeffrycopps I don't have a skill at making myself clear, so I'll try to make it better this time.The link you gave me, the answer is coded to check if all the keys are pressed at the **the same time**, I need to check if multiple keys are pressed e.g. UP, DOWN, LEFT, RIGHT, W, A, S, D. I **don't** want it to check if they're pressed **all** at the same time.

Comment: @HansPassant Could you please explain yourself more?

Comment: Google "windows forms game loop" to get somewhere.

Comment: @HansPassant It didn't help.

Comment: Are you meaning to say, you want a common action listener which will be able to handle any key press event?

Comment: It would help if you stated what data you want when keys are pressed in various sequences. For example, what information do you need for the following key press release sequence (D suffix means key down, U suffix means key up): `WD, WU, WD, AD, WU, AU, AD, WD, SD, WU, DD, WD, WU, AU, SU, DU`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The source of the problems is that this simple request is simply not supported under Winforms.

Sounds weird? It is. Winforms is often painfully close to the hardware layers and while this may be quite interesting at times, it also may be just a pita..

((One hidden hint by Hans should be noted: In the `KeyUp` you get told which key was released so you can keep track of as many keys as you want..))

But now for a direct solution that desn't require you to keep a bunch of `bools` around and manage them in  the `KeyDown` **and** `KeyUp` events..: Enter [Keyboard.IsKeyDown](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.keyboard.iskeydown%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

With it code like this works:

> Uses the `Keyboard.IsKeyDown` to determine if a key is down. 
>     `e` is an instance of `KeyEventArgs`.
>
> ```
> if (Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.Return)) {
>     btnIsDown.Background = Brushes.Red; }
> ...
> ```

Of course you can ceck for multiple key as well:

```
if (Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.A) && Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.W)) ...
```

The only requirement is that you borrow this from `WPF`:

First:  Add the namespace:

```
using System.Windows.Input;
```

Then:  Add two references to the project:

```
PresentationCore
WindowsBase
```

[image]

Now you can test the keyboard at any time, including the `KeyPress` event..

Answer (score 0):

Maybe for printing to the console...

```
if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.G))     {print ("G key pressed");}
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is:

1. Create a KeyDown event for the form
2. Write down the DllImports below in the class:

   ```cs
   [DllImport("user32")]
       public static extern int GetAsyncKeyState(int vKey);

   [DllImport("user32.dll")]
       public static extern int GetKeyboardState(byte[] keystate);
   ```
3. Write down the code below in the KeyDown Event:

   ```cs
           byte[] keys = new byte[256];

           GetKeyboardState(keys);

           if ((keys[(int)Keys.ControlKey] & keys[(int)Keys.S] & 128) == 128) // change the keys if you want to
           {
               // it worked
           }
   ```
4. Paste the code `this.KeyPreview = true;` in the Form_Load event and boom, there you go.

This is currently the best way to handle multiple Key events as it's a simple and straight up way for WinForms.

Answer (score -1):

You can achieve it using program level keyboard hook. You can use Win-API functions like  *SetWindowsHookEx*  in user32.dll.

Here are some examples of it :

[A Simple C# Global Keyboard Hook](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19004/A-Simple-C-Global-Low-Level-Keyboard-Hook) 
[Global keyboard capture in C# application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/604410/global-keyboard-capture-in-c-sharp-application)

Comment: Sorry but it didn't help, can you give an example?