# Is it possible to make a two letter keycode in windows form c#

Tags: c#, winforms, keycode

I've tried this one but it's not working.

```
     if (e.Control && e.KeyCode == Keys.B &&e.KeyCode == Keys.R )
        {
            btn.PerformClick();
        }
```

Comment: Can you describe which keystroke(s) you are trying to capture?

Comment: if i'm right, KeyCode is a flag enum, so you should handle it with ```e.KeyCode.HasFlag()```

Comment: Do you want the user to press `B` and `R` _simultaneously_ or _consecutively_?

Comment: I want when it is pressed consecutively

Comment: I am trying to capture "b" and "r"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to make sure that <kbd>B</kbd> is pressed and then followed by <kbd>R</kbd> would be to have a `bool` variable that indicates that <kbd>B</kbd> was pressed.

Here's a full example:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.KeyPreview = true;
        this.KeyDown += new KeyEventHandler(Form1_KeyDown);
    }

    bool readyForRKey;

    private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (readyForRKey && e.KeyCode == Keys.R)
        {
            btn.PerformClick();
        }

        readyForRKey = (e.KeyData == (Keys.Control | Keys.B));
    }
}
```

This will work if the user presses (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>, <kbd>R</kbd>) regardless of whether or they release the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key before pressing <kbd>R</kbd>.

If, on the other hand, you want to make sure that both <kbd>B</kbd> and <kbd>R</kbd> are pressed *at the same time*, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37884277) might help you.

Comment: @bekimpeci It works for me. Are you sure you're using the appropriate `KeyDown` event? I used `Form.KeyDown` just as an example. Obviously, you need to use it with the target/active control. Or if you want to press the key combination anywhere, you can use `Form.KeyDown` but make sure the `KeyPreview` property is set to true.

Answer (score 0):

Please try ProcessCmdKey() like this

```
protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
{
    if(keyData == (Keys.Control | Keys.B|Keys.R))
    {
        btn.PerformClick();
        return true;
    }

    return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
}
```