# C# Winform app - Cant make a specific keys combo

Tags: c#, winforms

im making a two player game in c# Windows Forms Application and i encountered a very weird problem: Im using timers for character movement - player 1 using arrows and player 2 using WSAD .I enable timers on keydown and disable them on keyup, and the problem is when player 1 using Down ***and*** left ( diagonal - South West) and player 2 using D ( trying to move right ), player 2 cant move right and he is stuck on this place, and player 1 is moving successfully. it does not happen with any other combo of keys - only when holding Left, Down and D together.
I dont think there is anything wrong with my code, but:

```
private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
       {
           if (!dohef)
           {
               if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Up)
                   timer1.Start();
               if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Down)
                   timer2.Start();
               if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Right)
                   timer3.Start();
               if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Left)
                   timer4.Start();
               if (e.KeyCode == Keys.W)
                   timer5.Start();
               if (e.KeyCode == Keys.S)
                   timer6.Start();
               if (e.KeyCode == Keys.D)
                   timer7.Start();
               if (e.KeyCode == Keys.A)
                   timer8.Start();
           }

       }

private void Form1_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (!dohef)
            {
                if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Up)
                    timer1.Stop();
                if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Down)
                    timer2.Stop();
                if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Right)
                    timer3.Stop();
                if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Left) // yahol leavi 3
                    timer4.Stop();
                if (e.KeyCode == Keys.W)
                    timer5.Stop();
                if (e.KeyCode == Keys.S)
                    timer6.Stop();
                if (e.KeyCode == Keys.D) // yahol leavi 3
                    timer7.Stop();
                if (e.KeyCode == Keys.A)
                    timer8.Stop();
            }
        }
```

if u look at the code, there is nothing wrong with what i did so tell me if i have to also paste the code of the timers, i didnt do it because it is very long and complicated.
BTW the boolean dohef has nothing to do with that, if he was True, so player 1 could not move diagonally, but he can - only player 2 cant move when i make this key combo. 
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: See: [Capture multiple key downs in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/a/709641/880990)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Capture multiple key downs in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/709540/capture-multiple-key-downs-in-c-sharp)