# KeyHook used to detect multiple keys pressed at the same time

Tags: c#, visual-studio, keyhook

Hi i have created a program to monitor the keyboard and if CTRL+Shift+R are pushed the the program must start recording the keys and write them to a text file.

I have got the second part(monitoring keys and writing to text file) working perfectly unfortunately my system cannot detect if ctrl+Shift+R have been pressed at the same time. I will sho the class i am using as well as the problem code

My class i am using for keyhook

```
public class LowLevelKeyboardListener
{
    private const int WH_KEYBOARD_LL = 13;
    private const int WM_KEYDOWN = 0x0100;
    private const int WM_SYSKEYDOWN = 0x0104;

    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern IntPtr SetWindowsHookEx(int idHook, LowLevelKeyboardProc lpfn, IntPtr hMod, uint dwThreadId);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    private static extern bool UnhookWindowsHookEx(IntPtr hhk);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern IntPtr CallNextHookEx(IntPtr hhk, int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern IntPtr GetModuleHandle(string lpModuleName);

    public delegate IntPtr LowLevelKeyboardProc(int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

    public event EventHandler<KeyPressedArgs> OnKeyPressed;

    private LowLevelKeyboardProc _proc;
    private IntPtr _hookID = IntPtr.Zero;

    public LowLevelKeyboardListener()
    {
        _proc = HookCallback;
    }

    public void HookKeyboard()
    {
        _hookID = SetHook(_proc);
    }

    public void UnHookKeyboard()
    {
        UnhookWindowsHookEx(_hookID);
    }

    private IntPtr SetHook(LowLevelKeyboardProc proc)
    {
        using (Process curProcess = Process.GetCurrentProcess())
        using (ProcessModule curModule = curProcess.MainModule)
        {
            return SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, proc, GetModuleHandle(curModule.ModuleName), 0);
        }
    }

    private IntPtr HookCallback(int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
    {
        if (nCode >= 0 && wParam == (IntPtr)WM_KEYDOWN || wParam == (IntPtr)WM_SYSKEYDOWN)
        {
            int vkCode = Marshal.ReadInt32(lParam);

            if (OnKeyPressed != null) { OnKeyPressed(this, new KeyPressedArgs(KeyInterop.KeyFromVirtualKey(vkCode))); }
        }

        return CallNextHookEx(_hookID, nCode, wParam, lParam);
    }
}

public class KeyPressedArgs : EventArgs
{
    public Key KeyPressed { get; private set; }

    public KeyPressedArgs(Key key)
    {
        KeyPressed = key;
    }
}
```

my problem code that is not being detected

```
 public void _listener_OnKeyPressed(Object sender, KeyPressedArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyPressed == Key.LeftCtrl && e.KeyPressed == Key.LeftShift && e.KeyPressed == Key.R)
        {
            if (recording)
            {
                System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Recording");
                recording = false;
            }
            else
            {
                System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Recording Halted");
                recording = true;
            }                  
        }
```

Some other code that i am using but works 100%

```
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        _listener = new LowLevelKeyboardListener();
        _listener.OnKeyPressed += _listener_OnKeyPressed;

        _listener.HookKeyboard();

        Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog dlg = new Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog();
        dlg.ShowDialog();
        pathName = dlg.FileName;
    }

    private void Window_Closing(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        _listener.UnHookKeyboard();
    }
```

I have tested the hook and it works perfectly if i only check if a single key has been pressed but does not work if i want to check if multiple keys have been pressed .

Comment: well ... the interrupt is raised for every key, thus you need to keep track what keys are pressed or look those keys states up

Comment: How would i look up those states?

Answer (score -1):

try using

```
if(Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.LeftShift) && Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.LeftCtrl) && Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.R)){ //do something }
```

also it might help you

[Capture multiple key downs in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/709540/capture-multiple-key-downs-in-c-sharp/709641#709641)